# img tag with two quotes in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm creating a component to upload a picture and then display it after the picture is uploaded. However, I'm getting the response link of the image with a double quote and the `<img>` tag adds another double quotes to the image link hence the image doesn't get displayed. I've tried `.slice(1,-1)` but it isn't working as well. How do I correctly display the image with just a single double quotes in the `<img>` tag.

```
<template>
      <img :src="srcUrl" /> 
</template>

<script>
uploadFile(file) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", file);
      const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

      request.addEventListener("readystatechange", () => {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
          const uploadedUrl = request.response;
          this.srcUrl = uploadedUrl; //getting a link with double quotes here and used slice but didn't work
        }
      });
      request.open("POST", "BaseURI");
      request.send(formData);
    },
</script>
```

Comment: Could you post an example URL with all the quotes pls ?

Comment: Why wouldn't `slice(1, -1)` work?

Comment: @kissu `<img src="&quot;https://storage.googleapis.com/gx-application-files/15600fr9-723d-4ba4-a1cd-4a2d2c916b5c/1abdb1a8-b5d5-44e1-a89f-960e22a0fb77&quot;">` this is what I got when I did inspect element and copied the link. although it shows two double quotes in the element section with the first double quotes being gray color and the second double quotes as blue color

Comment: I'm not really sure. I tried it but it didn't work. also look at my previous comment. when I copied the element then I got @quot instead of `"`.  @Daniel_Knights

Comment: Oh, in that case, you could do `.slice(6, -6)`

Comment: @Daniel_Knights I did that and the returned url had no `https`. It starts from `:` for the url. it's really strange. why is this behaviour?

Comment: Something is poorly parsed here, you should not have to do it.

Comment: @kissu is it something to do with the backend?

Comment: Not sure where it comes from, check your network tab, if the response is a clean regular-double-quoted string. But yeah, you should not have to mess with encoding.

Comment: Try `.replace('&quot;', '')` instead. @kissu's right though, if you have control over the backend you should send it without quotes

Comment: @Daniel_Knights it again sends with the two double quotes

Comment: @kissu there's a double quote in the response in the network tabs. should it be without the quotes?

Comment: So `""https://storage...""` or `"https://storage..."` ?

Comment: @kissu `"https://storage..."`

Comment: Could you try running your call with `axios` or `fetch` ? Maybe it's `XMLHttpRequest` the culprit here.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/MDGqplj this is how it shows in the networks tabs @kissu

Comment: @kissu how do I do the same request with fetch? I'm quite new actually :/

Comment: Ooooh, it should actually return you a JSON here, like `{ "url": "https..." }` and not directly the string. The issue is the backend. Try to fetch this API and check the result it sends you: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1/photos If you achieve to make it work with this, it's that your frontend code is correct.

Comment: it's a graphql backend though, not rest. should graphql also send the same way @kissu

Comment: I'm not a GraphQL pro, I'm using Apollo and the requests are a bit more complex to do, you need to make a [`query`](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/) and fetch the data that way. I can show you a basic REST example but Gql is hard to mock.

Comment: @kissu so it can't be done like the way I'm doing now? The request is being send though and I'm getting the response too, right.. since after slicing (6,-6), the `img` tag starts from `:` instead of `https` so I tried `:src="'https'+srcUrl" ` but then it slices the other end of the url too and I'm not sure how to include that part

Comment: If you're using gql on the backend, you should use Apollo or alike to handle the request. Even if it can somehow be done with Axios too I guess, it will be pretty ugly code. I'm trying to mock you an example, just found a gql playground with images.

Answer (score 1):

Update: you're trying to get some results from an API but we learned that it was actually a graphql one, so here is how the whole process is looking.

So, this is how a graphql playground looks like. You input your params on the left (`query`) and you get your result on the right, in `data`.
[image]

Here you can see my `photo` query, I have another one on the other tab.
`photos query` below:

```
query {
  photos {
    data {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, those are equivalent to REST `GET`. It's just a bit more complex to understand and a totally different backend organization.

I achieved to find a make you some codesandbox to illustrate how it works, here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/somehow-working-graphql-example-3rqvj?file=/src/components/Photos.vue

The endpoint of the gql can be found in `main.js` aka https://graphqlzero.almansi.me/api. You can play in it without any code, it's ready to be used as is: write your query on the left and press the "play" button !
You also do have some useful `docs` section on the right, it may help you somehow.
[image]

The linked project do have all the gql calls in `/graphql/` and the `Photos.vue` is an example on a possible way to make the call (there are several). The current setup only works for a single `ApolloQuery` so...if you want to see the result, comment one and see the other. If they are both un-commented at the same time it will not work but it comes down to configuration and it tedious and not really interesting to replicate it there...
You may also need to hard refresh it or to relaunch the sandbox because the dynamic import is messing pretty hard here... Maybe, the simplest way would be to just clone this and try it locally tbh.

---

So yeah, you do have it. It is how you can fetch an URL from a graphql API and display it on your page.
I can **heavily** recommend you taking this quick free course on Youtube to understand a bit better how this whole thing works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygUDIeiYZNA&list=PLTRTpHrUcSB--g_8qkmycKyB0WAua9sZR

[image]

Hope it somehow helped, cannot do more right now.